# Stepwise regression and mediation analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, mediation, stepwise-regression

In my research I have 3 domains of IV, 4 of MV and 8 of DV. To run mediation analysis I made possible chains from the results of stepwise regression and only one chain fulfilled the assumptions of mediation. Then I made the possible chains from the results of correlation and 12 possible chains fulfilled the mediation. Now how it can be possible that a variable is not emerging as a predictor in stepwise regression but it is fulfilling mediation assumption.

Or a variable is a significant predictor in stepwise results but it is not significant through enter method of regression?